# Connect database (SQL server compact 4.0) with c++

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I want to connect my c++ code with SQL server compact 4.0 in Visual studio 2012 basically I want to store and retrieve  data from the database I need C++ code or any good reference .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for managed code you can basically work with sql server compact just like you would with the "real" sql server ... just use SqlCexxx .net classes instead of Sqlxxx ... for example SqlCeCommand/SqlCeDataAdapter if you want to work with ado.net ... or you try entity framework where you should not need to care about the underlying kind of sql server at all ...